# How to access a pointer of struct in a struct using a function?

Tags: c

Actually I don't know what to except to ask for explanation to something I don't know what to call. I want to modify the "Date *d" which is in "Train *t".

```
typedef struct date{
      char dateDepart[MAX_VAL];
      int mois;
      int jour;
      int annee;
}Date;
```

```
typedef struct train{
    int numero;
    char villeDepart[MAX_VAL];
    char villeArrivee[MAX_VAL];
    Date *d;
}Train;
```

And I got this function that modifies the Train variables.

```
void getTrain(Train *t){
    printf("Saisie Train: ");
    scanf("%d",&t->numero);
    printf("Ville Depart: ");
    scanf("%s",&t->villeDepart);
    printf("Ville Arrivee: ");
    scanf("%s",&t->villeArrivee);
    printf("=========== Date Depart ============\n");
    getDate(t->d);
    printf("====================================\n");
}
```

And when it comes to `getDate` it doesn't work and the executable program quits. I guess it's segmentation fault. I am not an expert to be honest. but i'll be more than happy if someone helps me with the problem of `getTrain`. I guess there is a problem with the pointer. I don't know.

This is the `getDate` function

```
void getDate(Date *d){
    printf("Jour: ");
    scanf("%d",&d->jour);
    printf("Mois: ");
    scanf("%d",&d->mois);
    printf("Annee: ");
    scanf("%d",&d->annee);
    char tmp [MAX_VAL]; itoa(d->jour,tmp,10);
    strcat(d->dateDepart,tmp);
    strcat(d->dateDepart,"/");
    itoa(d->mois,tmp,10);
    strcat(d->dateDepart,tmp);
    strcat(d->dateDepart,"/");
    itoa(d->annee,tmp,10);
    strcat(d->dateDepart,tmp);
}
```

and this is the main code.

```
int main(){
    Train *t;
    getTrain(t);
    putTrain(t);
}
```

putTrain is just for printing.

Comment: there is the ```getDate```
```
void getDate(Date *d){
    printf("Jour: ");
    scanf("%d",&d->jour);
    printf("Mois: ");
    scanf("%d",&d->mois);
    printf("Annee: ");
    scanf("%d",&d->annee);
}
```

Comment: When you call this function, does t->d point to a Date that you created?

Comment: You don't show enough code. We need to see the function `getDate` and how you prepare the variable of type `Train` which is passed to `getTrain`. Please [edit] your question and add the missing parts. Don't use comments to add information.

Comment: @user253751 i guess that's the whole problem, because i don't know to what that exactly points.

Comment: Show how you initialize and populate `t` and `t->d`.

Comment: @j1kk4 Well, what does `t` point to? the variable t contains the address of a `struct Train` that you created somewhere, right?

Comment: when i type d->jour it closes the program right after i enter it.

Comment: You are working with pointers, pointers need to points to something (address), either reference to existing object/variable, or to dynamically allocated memory block, that is your problem. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

Comment: Basic question: Do you know what a pointer is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access to pointers that are not initialized. If you work with pointers, you need to properly assign address to these pointers, and in your case, dynamically allocated memory blocks:

```
Train *t = (Train*)malloc(sizeof(Train));
t->d = (Date*)malloc(sizeof(Date));

// do something...

free(t->d);
free(t);
t = NULL;
```

Notice that you are not forced to work with dynamically allocated memory, you could for example declare your Train structure as follow:

```
typedef struct train{
  int numero;
  char villeDepart[MAX_VAL];
  char villeArrivee[MAX_VAL];
  Date d;                     //< not a pointer
} Train;
```

Then use your structures as follow:

```
int main(){
  Train t;
  getTrain(&t);  //< reference (pointer) to t
  putTrain(&t);  //< reference (pointer) to t
}
```

In this case, you also have to modify the way you access to `d` to pass to `getDate` function:

```
getDate(&t->d); //< reference (pointer) to d member of t
```